# MVC Models, Entity Framework and binding dropdowns best practice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model, asp.net-mvc-5

Extremely basic question about best practice in MVC when binding drop down lists.

This inst a real world example but a basic example that explains my question:

Take the following model

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }     
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Car Car { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Make {get; set;{}
    public string Model {get; set;}
}
```

Then assume that these get flattened into a view model:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public int PersonID;
    public string Name;
    public int SelectedCarID;
    public SelectList<Cars> Cars;
}
```

In my constructor I have an index method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var person = _ctx.People.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ID == 1);

    var vm = new IndexViewModel(){
        Name = person.Name,
        SelectedCarID = person.Car.ID,
    };

    return View(vm);
}
```

Now, Assume that the person that is returned from the context has NO car record when the page first loads.
The view has a line :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SelectedCarID, Model.Cars)
```

When the form is submitted it is picked up by the action :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IndexViewModel model)
{
    var person = _ctx.People.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ID == model.PersonID);

    var car = _ctx.Cars.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ID == model.SelectedCarID);

    person.Name = model.name;
    person.Car = car;

    _ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Now that is the way I have done it for ages, I started using EF back when LINQ to SQL was taking off and I have always created my models like that as I was under the imperssion that it was the recommended way.
After a discussion with another developer today I am not sure if this is stil the best way? It has always irked me that I need to do a lookup against the database to get the Car record out just so that I can update the record.

My questions are:

1. What is the best way to achive what I have described above?
2. Is the above correct?
3. Is there a better way to update the car entity against the person without doing a lookup (Preferably without including the foreign keys in the model)?
4. Is it better to just include the FKs in the model (Its not the way Ive been doing it bit it seems more sensible)?
5. Is there a way to bind the drop down to the car object (The guy I spoke to seemed to suggest you could but my knowlege of MVC/asp.net and furious googling seems to indicate that you cant)?

Comment: Not relevant to the question but I wanted to point out that in a real world application some of the above would be using automapper and I wouldnt have the context referenced in the controller like that - I have been a developer for years - I do (more or less) know what I am doing.
Sometimes its good to question the ways we do things and get other peoples opinions, thats what I am trying to do here!

We work in a profession where learning never really stops, in this case I would really appreciate the input of the community.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This really ins't the place for Best Practices sort of questions (that would probably be [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)).

However some notes initially.

**Keep your domain objects in the domain**

The first thing that stood out to me was the `SelectList<Car>` property. Where it appears as your `Car` entity is actually a domain entity. A domain entity should not be exposed to the UI for multiple reasons.

1. Entity framework proxy classes monitor changes to properties that can be inadvertently saved.
2. Re-factoring of domain entities requires re-factoring of UI Code.
3. Domain entities typically contact properties you would not like exposed or otherwise.
4. Serialization of the Domain Entities will also serialize navigation properties and (mostly likely) cause circular reference errors.

#### Your question

Given the above you know have your answer, you will have to do a lookup for an entity based on your criteria from your View Model. Your view model should not have any understanding of the data context. It is in fact a `View Model` not a `Domain Entity`. By telling your View Model to interact with your data contexts you have no separation between your *Data Access* layers and your *Presentation* layers.

#### Don't make your controller manage data access as well

Your controller has a lot of work to-do, managing data access shouldn't be one of them. Doing so you have infarct coupled your Presentation Layer with your Data Access layer. Now as this is an example its easy to forgive however re factoring your data access layer will have direct consequences to your Presentation layer. I would suggest places a Services layer in between your data access layer and the presentation layer.

#### Ok All this in practice how does it look.

This is my personal approach here but will look at decoupling the data layer from the Presentation layer, no domain objects passed to the Presentation layer and using services to broker the transactions to the data layer.

#### Sample Service

This service is responsible for handling the interaction between the data layer and presentation (note mock repositories).

```
public class SampleService
{
    public SampleService()
    {
        _dbContext = new SampleContext();
    }

    readonly SampleContext _dbContext;

    public virtual Person GetPersonById(int id)
    {
        return _dbContext.Persons.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
    }

    public virtual Car GetCarById(int id)
    {
        return _dbContext.Cars.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
    }

    public virtual IList<Car> GetAllCars()
    {
        return _dbContext.Cars.ToList();
    }

    public virtual void UpdatePerson(Person person)
    {
        if (person == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(person));

        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public virtual void UpdateCar(Car car)
    {
        if (car == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(car));

        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Does this appear to be more work, absolutely does but better to implement your service now than have to do it later. What we also achieve is one location to update if we wish to change any queries or interaction methods.

#### IndexViewModel

As we have agreed we are no longer passing the car object to the `SelectList`. Infact we only need to construct a basic `IList<SelectListItem>` and populate this from our controller.

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public IndexViewModel()
    {
        AvailableCars = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }

    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int SelectedCarId { get; set; }

    public IList<SelectListItem> AvailableCars { get; set; }
}
```

#### Controller

Now our controller is pretty simple to wire up.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var person = sampleService.GetPersonById(1);
    var model = new IndexViewModel
    {
        Name = person.Name,
        PersonID = person.ID,
        SelectedCarId = person.Car.ID
    };

    model.AvailableCars = sampleService.GetAllCars()
                                        .Select(car => new SelectListItem
                                        {
                                            Text = $"{car.Make} - {car.Model}",
                                            Value = car.ID.ToString()
                                        })
                                        .OrderBy(sli => sli.Text)
                                        .ToList();
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IndexViewModel model)
{
    var person = sampleService.GetPersonById(model.PersonID);
    if(person != null)
    {
        person.Name = model.Name;

        //only update the person car if required.
        if(person.Car == null || person.Car.ID != model.SelectedCarId)
        {
            var car = sampleService.GetCarById(model.SelectedCarId);
            if (car != null)
                person.Car = car;
        }

        sampleService.UpdatePerson(person);
    }
    return View();
}
```

#### View Drop Down list

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCarId, Model.AvailableCars)
```

If you compare your code to my code I have actually added more code to the solution, however removes a lot of coupling and dependencies that could become hard to manage in larger applications.

Now back to your original questions.

> 3. Is there a better way to update the car entity against the person without doing a lookup (Preferably without including the foreign keys
>      in the model)?

No, you should be doing a lookup for that entity (car) outside of the Model. The model should not be aware of the data context.

> 4. Is it better to just include the FKs in the model (Its not the way Ive been doing it bit it seems more sensible)?

NO, your model should not be aware of the data context, therefore you do not need to define foreign keys (in a data context sense) leave that to your controller and services.

> 5. Is there a way to bind the drop down to the car object (The guy I spoke to seemed to suggest you could but my knowlege of MVC/asp.net
>      and furious googling seems to indicate that you cant)?

You could, but you don't want to. Our `Car` entity is a domain entity and we dont want to expose the entity to the UI (Presentation). Instead we will use other classes to expose what properties are bound. In this example a simple `IList<SelectListItem>` was more than sufficient.

Comment: Agree with @Nico used to do it your way but once i started using a services layer to deal with all that have never gone back just makes any future changes/updates much more easier esp if you end up using your entities in a lot of places

Comment: Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comments, most of the points that you flagged as being bad practice were down to me throwing an example together - in  proper application there would have been a seperate CarVM that would have been referenced and I do have a services layer - was just trying to keep things simple.
One comment about your service that you have there - you have an instance of a context- would you have one context per service? Normally I use Castle to inject the same context instance into all services.

Comment: "NO, your model should not be aware of the data context, therefore you do not need to define foreign keys (in a data context sense) leave that to your controller and services"
- I think the question was should the FKs be included in the data model, allowing the setting of the CAR by doing person.CarID = ViewModel.SelectedCarID; Which would save a lookup to the database to retrieve the car just to update the person record (Which is one of the points in the question) - This is something that I also do, I don't put the FKs in the data model but do sometimes think it would be easier... Opinions?